# Prevent a href button to submit a form PHP

Tags: html

Let's say I have a simple form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/"><button>Visit Google</button></a>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next step">
</form>
```

I've realized that both buttons perform the same action: submitting the form. Any simple way to leave the button inside the form and make it perform as a href?

Comment: Nesting an interactive element such as `button` into `a` is invalid HTML to begin with. Use a normal link without a button in it, and format it via CSS to give it the button _look_ you’re after.

Comment: Let's turn the question around: why do you want to use a `<button>` element if you *don't* want it to interact with the form? Is it just for styling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add type attribute to your button
This is wrong way to implement buttons either just keep anchor or button with onclick action which redirect user to http://google.com

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <a href="http://www.google.com/"><button type="button">Visit Google</button></a>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next step">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a link in a html element and design it with CSS.
I used boostrap library to get quick result. But maybe you goal is different.
Do you want to send  different a http request by your new button?

js traitement+element:=>

```js
$("#likeboutton").on("click",function(){//some code

console.log("insert you desire traitement")})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <h3  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="likeboutton" >Something</h3>
```